# Trace.Write(string, string) and Trace.WriteLine(string, string) don't filter by category

Tags: c#, .net, logging

When using a Trace.Listener can anyone tell me why the

```
Trace.Write(string message, string category)
```

doesn't pass the category string to the TraceFilter when the method

```
Trace.Write(object o, string category)
```

does pass the category string to the ShouldTrace method. Below are decompiles of both methods from Reflector. Just wondering why the .NET team would do something on one method and not on another method.

```
public virtual void Write(object o, string category)
{
    if ((this.Filter == null) || 
 this.Filter.ShouldTrace(null, "", TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, category, null, o))
    {
        if (category == null)
        {
            this.Write(o);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Write((o == null) ? "" : o.ToString(), category);
        }
    }
}
```

and then the string method.

```
public virtual void Write(string message, string category)
{
    if ((this.Filter == null) || 
         this.Filter.ShouldTrace(null, "", TraceEventType.Verbose, 0, message))
    {
        if (category == null)
        {
            this.Write(message);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Write(category + ": " + ((message == null) ? string.Empty : message));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are we suppose to know the reason?  The two method use two different overrides of the same method that is the reason for the different behavior.

Comment: Well i'm hoping someone has more insight to this inconsistency than me. Thank you for commenting though.

Comment: well phrased and formatted question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `this.Write` in the first overload

```
this.Write((o == null) ? "" : o.ToString(), category);
```

delegates the actual output to the second overload

```
public virtual void Write(string message, string category)
```

All of the formatting for the output is then centralized in the second overload:

```
this.Write(category + ": " + ((message == null) ? string.Empty : message));
```

By centralizing the actual formatting in this way, changing the formatting in a single place will change all trace output formatting. It's an application of [DRY principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).